# Is there a way to use checkinstall without mounting /var/tmp as exec?

Tags: linux, mount, checkinstall

I'm compiling nginx from source and wanted to use checkinstall so it can be uninstalled more easily later. The problem is that checkinstall executes scripts in /var/tmp which I mounted with noexec to prevent privilege escalation.

I found [this site](https://serialized.net/2010/03/getting-around-tmpfs-noexec-problems/) which recommends temporary binding /var/tmp to a different place to allow script execution in /var/tmp. But doesn't that cause problems with running processes that use /var/tmp at that moment and render me vulnerable?

Which brings me to the question is there a way to use checkinstall without mounting /var/tmp as exec? Maybe using chroot or unshare?

Answer (score 0):

## Explaination

One can use the unshare command to create a namespace dedicated to a script:

```bash
unshare --mount /path/to/script # Execute command in dedicated mount namespace
```

The script than uses its own mount namespace.
It could look like this:

```bash
mount --make-rslave /            # Prevent this mount namespace
                                 # from changing the real namespace
mount --bind /foo/tmptmp foo/tmp # Do the bind
touch /foo/tmp/tmpFile           # Create tmp files
echo $( ls /foo/tmptmp )
echo $( ls /foo/tmp )
#output:
#tmpFile
#tmpFile
```

After the script is executed using unshare lets look what happend to the main system.

```bash
ls /foo/tmptmp
#output: tmpFile
ls /foo/tmp
#output: 
#(Note that the file is only present in /foo/tmptmp)
umount /foo/tmptmp
#output: umount: /foo/tmptmp: not mounted
#(Note that the bind did only affect the mount namespace of the script)
```

## Solution

Applying this to the problem of the question yields the following script which needs to be called via unshare --mount:

```
mount --make-rslave /
mount --bind /your/tmp/file /var/tmp
checkinstall
```